# Prestashop product review module

Tags: module, prestashop

i am currently creating a webstore with prestashop and i would like a free product review module, but i could not find any. Can you point me to such a module?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: hire a developer to create a module if you couldnt find one u require or you can post it as a project at freelancer.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prestashop has a built in "Product Comments" module. (In the "Front End Features section of the Modules tab)
You can also add a start rating system (called Criterion).